# Django - DateTime Model field saving time as midnight

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm experiencing an unusual and frustrating challenge: I have formatted the date/time input inside of the form so it knows what format I'm sending it in, the form validates, and there are no challenges with the data, however when it's saving it saves the time as midnight no matter what way I plug it in.

The failing value is sample_date, in the below model.

Database Pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0cVh.jpg

**Model**

```py
class WaterTest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sample_date = models.DateTimeField()
    sample_address = models.TextField()
    mailing_address = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    sample_point = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    job_site = models.ForeignKey(JobSite, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    template = models.ForeignKey(Template, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    collected_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}: {self.sample_address}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Water Test'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Water Tests'
```

**Form**

```py
class CreateWaterTestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    sample_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'])

    class Meta:
        model = WaterTest
        fields = ['name', 'sample_date', 'sample_address', 'mailing_address', 'sample_point', 'job_site', 'template',
                  'collected_by']
```

**create_report.html**

```py
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="mb-3">
        {{ form.sample_date.errors }}
        <label class="form-label" for="{{ form.sample_date.id_for_label }}">Sample Date/Time <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
        {{ form.sample_date|add_class:"form-control" }}
    </div>
</div><!-- Col -->
```

```js
<script>
  $("#{{ form.sample_date.id_for_label }}").datetimepicker({
    {% if THEME == 'demo2' %}theme: 'dark',{% endif %}
    format: 'm/d/Y H:i'
  });
</script>
```

DateTime picker: https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

GitHub: https://github.com/varlenthegray/wcadmin/tree/dev

Answer (score 0):

The solution was far simpler than I expected. Make sure that your form definition matches everything else, or it'll just expect only the date!

**forms.py**

```py
class CreateWaterTestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    sample_date = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'])

    class Meta:
        model = WaterTest
        fields = ['name', 'sample_date', 'sample_address', 'mailing_address', 'sample_point', 'job_site', 'template',
                  'collected_by']
```